# Сохранение данных в форме. C#

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть кусок когда, который отвечает за открытие дочерней формы в главной.

```
private Form activeForm = null;
    private void openChildForm(Form childForm, object btnSender)
    {
        if (activeForm != null)
            activeForm.Hide();
        activeForm = childForm;
        childForm.TopLevel = false;
        childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panelChildForm.Controls.Add(childForm);
        panelChildForm.Tag = childForm;
        childForm.BringToFront();
        childForm.Show();
    }
```

Вызываю я так:

```
 private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openChildForm(new Settings(), sender);
        }
```

Проблема: Когда открываешь другую дочернюю форму и открываешь прошлою, то загружается новая форма и растёт потребление ОЗУ? Пытался использовать hide и show, результата не дало.

Вопрос: Как сделать, чтобы при повторном открытии формы, новая форма не создавалась и сохранялись ведённые данные?

Comment: `new Settings()` - создать новый объект. Естественно он у вас будет заново грузить все необходимое. Сохраняйте ссылку на ранее созданный объект и его используйте, а не постоянно `new`.

Comment: А не подскажите как сохранять ссылку на созданный объект?

Comment: Вы ведь это уже делаете, пустой `activeForm` в который вы после выполнения нужных действий передаете ссылку `activeForm = childForm;`, после чего у вас в `activeForm` ссылка на уже инициализированную форму.

Comment: потребление памяти растет, потому что перед "потерей" ссылки на форму, нужно у нее Dispose() вызывать. WinForms - обертка над WinAPI, почти все внутри - неуправляемые системные ресурсы, а вы их просто "забываете" и просите новые, при повторном создании формы.

Comment: Вот я хочу сделать чтобы они не забывались, но не знаю как